# Solr Concurrent Queries in Huge batches

Tags: java, apache-spark, solr, jetty, threadpool

I am using Solr 6.3.0 with java CloudSolrClient which accepts zookeeper url.

I have a 5 node Solr cloud cluster, with 2 shards per node and 1 replica, i.e total 20 shards

I need to update some data regularly by querying from Solr, I have to run around 3 million queries once a day,

My query is as:

For a unique ID:

1. Get termfreq() of values of a field, get top values(2 or 3) with max tf
2. Fire a query for other id's with least distance b/w those particular values in that field sort by it to get lookalike ids.

ex:

fq will be as:

```
(field_name:value_1 OR field_name:value_2 OR field_name:value_3 OR field_name:value_4 OR field_name:value_5)"
```

sort param as:

```
  {!func}dist(4,termfreq('field_name','value_0'),termfreq('field_name','value_1'),termfreq('field_name','value_2'),termfreq('field_name','value_3'),termfreq('field_name','value_4'),5,4,6,3,2) asc"
```

Here 5,4,6,3,2 are acquired as top tf for 5 from 1st query for value_1,value_2..

1 takes few ms
2 takes 120ms for the first time

I need to get 1000 rows from 2nd query for every 3 million

Any tweaks that will help me to reduce this?

I have tried Threadpool, average time for 1 query 150ms
Tried using spark with 10 exec but it weirdly took more time than thread pool.

I have monitored all 5 nodes, CPU usage is very high on all of them(while querying), but memory consumption is low(max 9GB out of 30 GB), I have set heap as - Xms is 8GB, Xmx is 15GB.

Filter Cache is 512mb(initial)-2GB(size).

I have tried many tweaks, still can't reduce query times, I can't parallelize this part of my code.

Thanks.